# How to copy a Excel column to a Java list

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

I would like to extract the entire column from an excel worksheet to a Java array using the Aspose library. How do I do that? In many of the examples, I see how to copy a column/row from one worksheet to another only. Can Aspose extract data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, data can be easily exported to an Array using the exportArray method, see the sample code for your reference:

**Example**

```
// Instantiating a Workbook object
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx");

// Accessing the first worksheet in the Excel file
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

// Exporting the contents of 100 rows and 1 column starting from 1st cell (i.e., A1:A100)
// to Array. you may update the method parameters for your needs
Object dataTable[][] = worksheet.getCells().exportArray(0, 0, 100, 1);

// Printing number of rows after exporting worksheet data
System.out.println("No. Of Rows Imported: " + dataTable.length);

.....
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Great! I'm trying to sort an excel file based on data in one of the columns. The problem here is that this column contains dot notations, i.e., 1, 1.1, 1.10, 1.10.1.
Treating these as strings will not work, nor is converting them to numbers. Is there a way to do this in Aspose?

Comment: Could you try using data sorting (MS Excel feature) via Aspose.Cells APIs, see the document for your reference:
https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Data+Sorting

If this does not fulfill your needs, kindly do provide your input file, output file and sample code for the issue. Also, provide your expected file (that you may create/update in Ms Excel manually), I will check it. You may zip the files and upload to some file sharing service and provide the download link here.